# Limit or upperbound of the limit $N \to +\infty \sum_{n=0}^{N} n \gamma^n$ for $0 < \gamma < 1$

Tags: limits

I would like to derive the limit (or an upperbound) of
$$\lim_{N\to  +\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{N} n \gamma^n$$ for $0 < \gamma < 1$

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you meant $N\to\infty$. In that case, note that
$$\sum_{n=0}^N n\gamma^n=\gamma\sum_{n=0}^N n\gamma^{n-1}=\gamma\sum_{n=0}^N\frac{d}{d\gamma}\left(\gamma^n\right)=\gamma\cdot\frac{d}{d\gamma}\left(\sum_{n=0}^N \gamma^n\right)=\gamma\cdot\frac{d}{d\gamma}\left(\frac{\gamma^N-1}{\gamma-1}\right)$$
Now you can compute the derivative and then take the limit.

Comment: I came with $\frac{1}{(1-\gamma)^2}$

Comment: @Samuele Which is equivalent to my answer.  Indeed, that is what you should've ended up with.

Comment: Thanks! I used your answer and I just wanted double-checking. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the generalized binomial expansion of $(1-\gamma)^{-2}$ is given by

$$(1-\gamma)^{-2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n\gamma^n$$

which converges for $|\gamma|<1$.